# google analytics 2 domain with multiple (infinite) subdomain goals setting

Tags: google-analytics

I have 2 domains, lets say:

1. domain-landing.com
2. domain-checkout.com

domain-landing.com has multiple (let's assume infinite) subdomains

1. foo.domain-landing.com
2. bar.domain-landing.com
3. hello.domain-landing.com
4. world.domain-landing.com
5. and so on...

For each sub-domain, there is a similar landing page that leads all traffic to domain-checkout.com

domain-checkout.com is a place where the transaction is done (checkout).
i have set up Destination-Type Goals on domain-checkout.com/checkout

But when i checked analytics report for Landing Page there's no conversion at all.

I have implemented this https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en

on *.domain-landing.com:

```
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['domain-checkout.com']);
```

on domain-checkout.com:

```
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['domain-landing.com']);
```

in my case, how to set up google analytics correctly, so I can track my total conversion from all subdomain on domain-landing.com?

Comment: The setup is the correct, if you have multiple domains needs the crossdomain tag, to make consistent the cookie on all the domains. But what makes me is the report, have you properly set the goals? to who is attributed the conversion? what source or medium? have you added the domains to the referral exclusion list? If you haven't added these subdomains, the session will be cut when the users jumps from one domain to another